# Regex to only allow leading zeros if it contains a decimal

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that looks like this:

```
bool(re.match('^(0|[.]{0,1}[1-9][.]{0,1}[0-9]*)$', "0.123"))
```

This works perfect, but it doesn't match for leading zeros when there contains a decimal like the above example. My objective is to only match leading zero numbers when they contain a decimal. Strings like: "01" should not be matched. Numbers that are decimal numbers or whole numbers can be matched.

How would I create a regex that matches for this?

Some scenarios:

```
0.01 Match
1 Match
1.2 Match
.01 Match
-0.1 Match
-1 Match
1.2.3 No Match
01 No Match
001.1 No Match
00.1 No Match
```

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223634/1997)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-regex approach which looks like passes all the mentioned test cases:

```py
numbers = """\
0.123
0
01
0.01
1
1.2
.01
-0.1
-1
1.2.3
-01.2
01
-01
001.1
00.1\
"""


def is_valid_num(s: str):
    unsigned_s = s.lstrip('-+')

    if unsigned_s.startswith('0'):
        try:
            if not unsigned_s[1] == '.':
                return False
        except IndexError:
            # It's just a zero (0)
            return True

    try:
        _ = float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n in numbers.split('\n'):
        print(f'{n:<10} -> {is_valid_num(n)!r:>10}')
```

Output:

```
0.123      ->       True
0          ->       True
01         ->      False
0.01       ->       True
1          ->       True
1.2        ->       True
.01        ->       True
-0.1       ->       True
-1         ->       True
1.2.3      ->      False
-01.2      ->      False
01         ->      False
-01        ->      False
001.1      ->      False
00.1       ->      False
```

Comment: There's a test case that should have been in the question, `-01.2` or even just `-01`.

Comment: @MarkRansom ah, good point

Comment: I updated it to cover the mentioned case :-)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you can use this regex:

```
^-?(((?!0)[0-9]+|0)(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)$
```

I'm not sure about `2.` if that is a number.
If it is, you can use:

```
^-?(((?!0)[0-9]+|0)(\.([0-9]+)?)?|\.[0-9]+)$
```